# How can I create a QR code that links to a specific cell in Google Sheets, but can be edited, not just viewed?

Tags: google-sheets

I am hoping to create an inventory spreadsheet that uses a QR code to bring up the inventory list, and then allows the person scanning the code to edit a blank cell to identify who the item was checked out to.

We have multiples of the same item, so I would like to be able to pull up only the item associated with that QR code instead of the entire spreadsheet.

I have figured out how to allow someone to view only the range associated with a QR code on a published document, but they need to be able to edit. 
Here is an example of the URL I am using to create a QR code for a specific rage of cells (1 item):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19IVyc2Zpc5iR5Lnjb8UD7ptb8qxkJU7CGMXKacILmdc/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true&range=A5:D5

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's not possible. Instead you could create a web app or gadget to create a web user interface or to use a Google Form.

I.E. you could use the [Awesome Table with and Google Form](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/available-web-apps/awesome-tables/using-a-form).

Awesome Table is a gadget that displays a spreadsheet content as an interactive web page. The above link shows buttons that open a Google form to edit a row in the displayed table. The spreadsheet connected to the gadget include the URLs you could use that URLs to generate the QR codes.